# Can't connect python to looker

Tags: python, looker

I've downloaded the looker_sdk for python. 
Wrote a very simple program:

```
from looker_sdk import client, models


def test_looker():
    sdk = client.setup("./looker.ini")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_looker()
```

However, when I'm running it I'm getting the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'client' from 'looker_sdk'.

I do see the models and was able to perform:

```
sdk = looker_sdk.init31()
```

what am I missing?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: Which version of python are you using and what is the version of looker_sdk? I have tested this myself with the latest version (python 3.8) and don't see this `ImportError`.

Comment: python 3.7 and looker_sdk- Version: 0.1.3b8

Comment: How did you install the package?

Comment: pip install looker_sdk. 
in my venv

Comment: Can you try uninstalling and re-installing the package?

Comment: it worked! I've uninstalled and re-installed the previous version (0.1.3b7) and now I do see the client. Not sure whether the problem was in my installation or in the version. 

Thank you very much! Much appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `client`? That `looker.ini` file is used to connect to LookerSDK, but you're already doing that with `sdk = looker_sdk.init31()`. So I'm not sure what you plan to do with `client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there may be a missing `client.py` file in looker_sdk version 0.1.3b8, or in your installation - I tested this on 0.1.3b4 and found no such issue.

I recommend that you uninstall the package and re-install the latest version from PyPI.